# Jenkins build error: What went wrong? Directory '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/doran' does not contain a Gradle build

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jenkins, gradle, settings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Directory '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/doran' does not contain a Gradle build.

A Gradle build should contain a 'settings.gradle' or 'settings.gradle.kts' file in its root directory. It may also contain a 'build.gradle' or 'build.gradle.kts' file.

Answer (score 0):

In the 'Invoke Gradle script' section:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f99GT.png)
click 'Advanced' --> 'Root Build script'
then change the directory to the location containing settings.gradle in your project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYkWA.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).